# Add GWT Widgets inside an iFrame in UIBinder?

Tags: javascript, java, html, iframe, gwt

I want to insert GWT Widgets like FlowPanel, HTMLPanel inside and iframe using GWT. I found [this](http://bealetech.com/blog/2010/01/25/embedding-html-document-in-an-iframe-with-gwt/) post which inserts content as a String into an iFrame. But, this does not help when I want to integrate other panels and widgets.

I find out how to insert GWT Widgets and Panels programmatically into GWT. Here is how I do it:

```
  public interface Resources extends ClientBundle {

    @Source({Css.DEFAULT_CSS})
    Css css();

  }

  public interface Css extends CssResource {

    String DEFAULT_CSS = "test/client/app/start/StartView.gss";

    String outerBox();
    String iframe();
    String test();

  }

  @UiField(provided = true)
  Resources resources;

  @UiField(provided = true)
  Messages messages;

  @Inject
  public StartView(final Binder binder, Resources resources, Messages messages)    
  {
    this.resources = resources;
    resources.css().ensureInjected();
    this.messages = messages;
    initWidget(binder.createAndBindUi(this));

    final IFrameElement iframe = Document.get().createIFrameElement();
    FlowPanel innerBox = new FlowPanel() {
       @Override
       protected void onLoad() {
         super.onLoad();

         FlowPanel p1 = new FlowPanel();
         p1.addStyleName(resources.css().test());

         HTMLPanel panel = new HTMLPanel("Hello World!");
         panel.setStyleName(resources.css().test());  // does not work
         p1.add(panel);

         final Document doc = iframe.getContentDocument();
         BodyElement body = doc.getBody();

         body.appendChild(p1.getElement());
         panel.setStyleName(resources.css().test());  // does not work
         p1.getElement().addClassName(resources.css().test()); // does not work

       }
    };
  }
```

My uiBinder:

```
<ui:with type="test.client.app.start.StartView.Resources" field="resources" />
<ui:with type="test.client.messages.Messages" field="messages" />

<g:FlowPanel ui:field="outerPanel" addStyleNames="{resources.css.outerBox}">
</g:FlowPanel>
```

The former code inserts GWT Panels into an iframe. The problem is that I cannot set any css style. Even if I set the style with:

```
panel.setStyleName(resources.css().test());  // does not work
p1.getElement().addClassName(resources.css().test()); // does not work
```

both variants do not work. I know I can inject a general css file in the head of the iframe document, but I want to use the GWT resources.

**How can I set the styles using CSS/GSS Resources for the Panels inside the iframe?**

Comment: Do you really need an iFrame? I think the newly created iFrame has a different domain as your GWT app. So you will have problems with the SOP. I would suggest to use a div - if possible.

Comment: I want to create a plugin which is embedded into a different page. Therefore I can only use iframe to ensure my own css.

Comment: Does the different page provide an area for your plugin? The different page has nothing to do with your app?

Comment: Please have a look at the chat widget here: https://www.livechatinc.com/ this is a good example. You need an iframe such that the css of the page does not override or influence your css.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to add content to the iframe programmatically using [IFrameElement](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/IFrameElement.html) and retrieving the iframe document with `getContentDocument()` in order to append the new content.

By the way you can still use UIBinder like this, in your view.ui.xml:

```
 <iframe  ui:field="container"/>
```

and in your View.java:

```
 @UiField IFrameElement container;
```

About CSS I think the main issue is that iframe is like a sandbox and does not share information with the parent document. My best guess is that you should clone your `<link/>` or `<style/>` element from the parent and append it into the `<head/>` of the child.

The final solution is:

```
    Event.sinkEvents(iframe, Event.ONLOAD);
    Event.setEventListener(iframe, new EventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
            StyleElement style = Document.get().createStyleElement();
            style.setInnerText(resources.css().getText());
            iframe.getContentDocument().getHead().appendChild(style);

            ParagraphElement pEl = Document.get().createPElement();
            pEl.setInnerText("Hallo World");
            pEl.addClassName(resources.css().whatever());
            iframe.getContentDocument().getBody().appendChild(pEl);
        }
    });
```

The event listener is necessary in order to retrieve the document from the iframe you should wait the frame to load it, even if it is an *about:blank*.

Comment: please see my edit. How do I get the css from my GWT resoures inside the iframe?

Comment: What do you mean my "clone you link element from the parent"? By the way you solution did not work you cannot do ``container.getContentDocument()``. It leads to an error.

Comment: Strange because it is exactly what you are doing. Anyway I mean that in the parent you should have the CSS but then you apply classes to element inside the iframe. In the iframe the CSS is not visible, the only way is to clone the same CSS into the iframe. Imaging that in the parent the CSS is included as `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="urltocss" charset="utf-8">` I would replicate this element into the iframe head.

Comment: I know what you mean. But in my parent I do not have a ``main.css``. I use the GWT CSSResources. So GWT inlines the css. Is there a way to use this inside an iframe to?

Comment: Try `MyResources.INSTANCE.css().ensureInjected();`

Comment: Do it after `initWidget(binder.createAndBindUi(this));` and please check if it is inline as you said, because sounds really strange to me.

Comment: This does not change anything.

Comment: Well you have to give me more information because this is not all the code necessary to run it. For example where are you initializing the resource? I do not see anything like `Resources INSTANCE = GWT.create(Resources.class);`

Comment: I use Google Gin. Resources is initialized by ``@Inject``. You can also use ``GWT.create(Resources.class);`` this is the same. What else do you need?

Comment: Yes css is working in the parent with no problems. GWT seems to have problems injecting the resources into the iframe.

Comment: What sounds strange to me that you see the css inline. Anyway I suggest to open a new question because you address the main point of this question.

Comment: The question is how to get the css working in the iframe.

Comment: Do you have an example where you could insert css resources into panel inside an iframe? If yes please post it.

Comment: Actually this scenario its not common at all. What about your ui.xml? Could you add it to complete all the pieces of the puzzle.

Comment: First it was not working because you should wait the iframe to load in order to append child. Regarding the CSS, `CssResource` provide a getText method http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/resources/client/CssResource.html#getText()

Comment: How do I wait for the iframe to load?

Answer (score 0):

An `<iframe>` can't contain child elements (they'll be ignored) since it's effectively a browser window nested in your document. You have to use its `src` attribute to specify a resource to load.

Comment: That is not true. See: http://bealetech.com/blog/2010/01/25/embedding-html-document-in-an-iframe-with-gwt/

Comment: @confile That's not "child elements" though.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer Do you have a solution for this problem?